# JS - Put Mouse coordonnate in Clipboard - Parallel Click Listener

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I'm trying to recover coordonnates of the mouse when the user click and then put these coordonnates in the clipboard of the user.

I succeed in getting coordonnates and put them in the clipboard.
But the coordonnate stored in the clipboard are from the previous click.
it's not from the actual click of the user.

**HTML**

```
<div id="divImg" class="center">
    <img id="img" class="img" src="src" alt="alt"/>
    <button id="clip"></button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(window).bind('click', imgCoord);
$('div#divImg button#clip').click(setClipboard);
```

**imgCoord()**

```
function imgCoord(){
      ***
      $('body').append('<textarea id="to-copy">'+x+','+y+'</textarea>');
}
```

**setClipboard**

```
function setClipboard(){
    if($('textarea#to-copy')){
        $('textarea#to-copy').select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
        $('textarea#to-copy').remove();
        return true;
    }
}
```

I assume $('textarea#to-copy') doesn't load the new DOM made by imgCoord() but I don't know how to fix this problem.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.

```
$(window).bind('mousedown', imgCoord);
$('div#divImg button#clip').bind('mouseup', setClipboard);
```

I put MouseDown on the function that get coordonnates and MouseUp on SetClipboard().

It build some kind of "queue"

I tried to do the same with SetTiemout earlier but it failed